# How I should insert shortcode based on div class using Astra Theme

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, elementor

I have a site with the following plugins

it has Astra Theme built with Elementor and Learn Dash for online courses.
I want to have following structure

```
Course Image (Controlled by Elementor)
Course Details (Controlled by Elementor)
Course Lessons (Controlled by LearnDash)
Review
Footer(Controlled by Elementor)
```

I try to add a review shortcode with Elementor for every Course page, but instead of having that after Course Lessons it is displayed before.

How can I add my shortcode after a div class="ld-item-list ld-lesson-list" using functions.php

A sample course is
https://asmathoume.gr/courses/%CF%84%CE%B1-%CE%B2%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC-%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%B1-%CE%B5%CE%BA%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B5%CF%85%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%8D%CF%82/

thank you